# Hi, I'm a beginner in sql. I have problem in (UDF) function scalar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

My function is:

```
Create Function [dbo].[FindMaxRadif](@field nvarchar(15), @tbl nvarchar(15))
    returns int
    as
    begin
        declare @query int
        set @query = 'select max('+ @field+') from '+ @tbl
        return (@query)
    end
```

when Execute this function with this command:

```
select dbo.FindMaxRadif('IdVehicle','TblVehicle')
```

I recive this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select
> max(IdVehicle) from TblVehicle' to data type int.

how to fix it?

Comment: You try to use Dynamic SQL, but you cannot use dynamic SQL in UDFs (you can in Stored Procedures)

Comment: @dnoeth - Look again... the OP is NOT trying to execute dynamic SQL in a function.  He's merely trying to concatenate parts into a string that could be used as dynamic SQL outside of the function.

Comment: @JeffModen Well, the OP tries to assign the string to an INT result, that's why it fails with a type conversion error.

Comment: @dnoeth - Yep... Agreed.  That's the only problem... not dynamic SQL like you said.

Comment: @JeffModen Of course it's dynamic SQL, he tries to assign the *result* of the count in the query string.

Comment: @dnoeth - Yes, I agree that he's building dynamic SQL in the function but that's like doing any other concatenation and is certainly allowed within a function.  He's NOT trying to execute (use) the dynamic SQL in the function like you said he did.

Comment: @JeffModen What else would you want when you try to run the Select and assign the result to an output variable? Remember, the OP is a beginner and newbies tend to think it's possible. Anyway, in both cases there's a solution, change the result datatype of David's answer :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - The bottom line is that the question wasn't originally answered.  Instead, everyone jumped on the OP about not being able to run dynamic SQL in a function instead of saying that all that was needed is to change the datatype and then maybe adding that they won't be able to execute it in the function. :D

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is not allowed in a User-Defined function.  They are not allowed to make data changes, and prohibiting dynamic SQL helps enforce that.  You can use a Stored Procedure instead, returning data either as a resultset:

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[FindMaxRadif] @field nvarchar(15), @tbl nvarchar(15)
as
/*
create table a(i int)
insert into a(i) values (1),(2);
exec FindMaxRadif 'i','a'
*/
begin
    declare @query nvarchar(max);
    set @query = concat('select max(', quotename(@field), ') from ', quotename(@tbl));
    
    --print @query
    exec(@query);
end
```

or an output parameter

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[FindMaxRadif2] @field nvarchar(15), @tbl nvarchar(15), @rv int output
as
/*
create table a(i int)
insert into a(i) values (1),(2);
declare @v int
exec FindMaxRadif2 'i','a', @v out
select @v
*/
begin
    declare @query nvarchar(max);
    set @query = concat('select @rv = max(', quotename(@field), ') from ', quotename(@tbl));
    
    --print @query
    exec sp_executesql @query, N'@rv int output', @rv = @rv output
end
```

Comment: The OP isn't trying to execute dynamic SQL in the function.  He's only trying to create the dynamic SQL, which IS allowed just like any other concatenation will be.